# Only the last item in the list gets saved

Tags: python, html, list, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have this snippet of code that is part of a larger file. When I run it, the output of the for loop is what I'm looking for and it prints fine; however, only the text from the last item gets saved to the .txt file. I'm new to python and I have a feeling this is a simple, newbie mistake but I'm stumped here. I thought making a new file at the top would solve that issue, but no luck.

```
with open("all_ctrl_pk_articles.txt","w") as f:
        f.write("")
        for url in ctrl_pk_list:
            re = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(re.content, "html.parser")
            g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "story-body-supplemental"})
            for item in g_data:
                print item.contents[1].text #WANT TO SAVE THIS TEXT
                source_code = requests.get(url)
                plain_text = source_code.text
                soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
                #print soup.text
                newsoup = soup.text
           f.write(newsoup)

        with io.open("all_ctrl_pk_articles.txt","a", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
           f.write(newsoup)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Your `print` is in the inner loop. Don't you want your `write` there too? Also, you will need to write a newline if there isn't one.

Comment: The write call needs to be in the loop.  Or, you need to append to newsoup instead of reassigning it.  Each time through the loop, "newsoup = soup.text" simply reassigns that name to new data.  You want to add to your data.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not writing to the file during the loop (You'll also have to change the "write" to "append" or else it'll get overwritten)

I hope this answers OP's question:

```
with open("all_ctrl_pk_articles.txt","a") as f:
        f.write("")
        for url in ctrl_pk_list:
            re = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(re.content, "html.parser")
            g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "story-body-supplemental"})
            for item in g_data:
                print item.contents[1].text #WANT TO SAVE THIS TEXT
                source_code = requests.get(url)
                plain_text = source_code.text
                soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
                #print soup.text
                newsoup = soup.text
                f.write(newsoup) #Put this in the loop

        with io.open("all_ctrl_pk_articles.txt","a", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
           f.write(newsoup)
    f.close()
```